# How to change color of html in page 2 by clicking the button in page 1

Tags: javascript, html

```
**page1.html**

     <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.querySelector(".example").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
</script>
```

```
**page2.html**

<h2 class="example">A heading with class="example"</h2>
```

The background color of the h2 tag with class named example won't change after clicked the button in page 1.

Comment: JavaScript can only interact with content in the page it is running in. (Or with content on the server it was loaded from, via Ajax). The exception might be if page2 was loaded into the browser as some sort of "child" of page1, e.g. in an iframe, or from a popup window

Comment: Is there any other solution to solve this issue?

Comment: Apart from what I've just listed, no. Imagine if random web pages could update the content of other random webpages which happened to be loaded into another tab of the same browser. It would be chaos! Hackers etc would have a field day. It's a good thing this is not possible

Comment: As others have said below, you can use various methods to pass data around between pages, but this assumes you are loading page2 later, whereas your code looks like it assumes that both pages are already loaded in different tabs. It might actually help if you clarify the exact scenario

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is using Local Storage who persist over pages on the same domain. Then in the target page read the value in "onload".

On the page1:

```
function myFunction() {
    localStorage.setItem("exampleBGColor", "red");
}
```

On the page2:

```
window.onload = function() {
    let BGcolor = localStorage.getItem("exampleBGColor");
    if(BGcolor) {
        document.querySelector(".example").style.backgroundColor = BGcolor;
        localStorage.removeItem("exampleBGColor");
    }
}
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

For making a change in another page it's not possible to directly access it from your page.

So you can do it from some innovative ways !

For Example :

- You can pass a parameter to another page ('page2') in your url and then in
  'page2' read it from query params and set the color for element.
- You can set the color in the localstorage and then in new page read
  it from localstorage and set the color of element.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve similar behavior using LocalStorage api.

First Page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Local Storage</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <script>
        function setColor() {
            localStorage.setItem('currentColor', 'red');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="setColor()">
        Change Color
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Second Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Local Storage</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {
            const div = document.getElementById('div');
            div.style.backgroundColor = e.key === 'currentColor' ? e.newValue : null;
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div">
        My Color Will Change
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using `storage` event listener allows div in Page 2 to update its color reactively.
You can learn more about LocalStorage [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Answer (score 0):

As @juanram0n, Ilia @Afzali and @dev_junwen said, you can make it by using JavaScript Window localStorage Property.

```
*page1.html*

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
 // Store backgroundColor
 localStorage.setItem("bgColor", "red");
}
</script>
```

```
*page2.html*

<h2 class="example">A heading with class="example"</h2>
<script>
document.querySelector(".example").style.backgroundColor = localStorage.getItem("bgColor");
</script>
```