# Go back to previous page without losing data

Tags: javascript, html, history

I have two web pages "Page_1.html" and "Page_2.html".
In the first page, the user enters some filters (value of select, input, etc..).
We acces to the second page from the first page.
When going back to the first page from the second, I would like to save the filters that the user entered at first.
Thank you

Comment: Seem that you need a server side component or maybe you can store the user selection in `localStorage`

Comment: You can try use a cookies.

Comment: Can I please have an example?

Comment: You can check and see if this is helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58777531/how-to-change-color-of-html-in-page-2-by-clicking-the-button-in-page-1/58777742#58777742

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are best for doing such things. This is how you can achieve it.

On first page

```
  <a onclick="setCookie()">page 2</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function setCookie(){
    document.cookie = "filter=value";
}
```

To retrieve the data on the second page you can use

```
var x = document.cookie; /*  "Key=value;key1=value1..." */

var filter = extract("filter", x);

 function extract(key, cookie){
   var a = cookie.split(";");
   a.forEach((el) => {
       var e = el.split("=");
       if(e[0] == key) {
          return e[1];
       }
   });
 }
```

`document.cookie` will return all the values as a single string  `"filter=value;key1=value1..."` in following format. All you need now is string manipulation and extract the value you required.  The extract function does this specific task.

It splits the string using `;` separating each cookie as element of array `["filter=value","key1=value1",...]"`.

Further looping for each element in the array. We split the value  using `=` which gives us `['filter','value']`. Just compare it with the key you want and will return the value if it matches.

> "make sure to use localhost server, as the cookies won't work for regular offline pages."

You should reserch more on how cookies are treated by browser and don't store sensitive information inside cookies, it's not a good practise to do so.

Hope this is helpful....

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a sessions. So you can use a Nodejs at the backend.